# Wits End: DVD Mounting in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, mount, dvd

Symptoms:

- I cannot mount a DVD
- MakeMKV Failed to get full access to drive . Make sure that you either have write access to device "dev/sr2, are member of "cdrom" group or have CAP_SYS_RAWIO enabled
- Attempts to manually mount DVD leads to "mount: /mnt/cdrom: no medium found on /dev/sr1."

What I have tried:

- CD works fine
- Replaced DVD drive
- Made sure my user was part of cdrom
- DVD works fine in OS X
- Manually mounting the drive
- Reinstalling 18.04
- Installing necessary codecs

Any help would be appreciated.

Running `groups` returns:
`<myusername> adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`

Comment: Which order did you do all these things in? What were the actual results of each? What does `lshw` say about it?

Comment: Also, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1199162/edit) your question and add the output of the command `groups` from a terminal window.  It should show if you are part of the `cdrom` group or not.

Comment: @waltinator lshw shows the [this](https://pastebin.com/KY6QBy6X)

Comment: Please edit your post to include new info. Data at the far end of a link doesn't get indexed by AskUbuntu, has a lifetime unconnected to the lifetime of the Question, and helps no future users.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message.

In my case, I installed `makemkv` in Ubuntu by using snap (i.e. by using the Ubuntu Software Store).

To solve the problem, I went into the snap store, clicked on "Installed", scrolled down to the makemkv item, clicked on it, clicked on "Permissions", turned on both of the "Read from CD/DVD" buttons (there were two for me, probably because I have two DVD drives).

I also turned on "Read/write files on removable storage devices" although that may not have been needed.